# Using Content API (graphql) to filter CPs related to a URL

Tags: sites-9, graphql, pca

With Sites 9 and the Content API, is there a way to query for the content associated with a page/url AND filter on component presentations whose components are tagged with specific keywords?  My initial thought is the use of Target Groups associated with component presentations as this seems to fit perfectly with regard to usecase.  I'll settle for query page by URL and filter component presentations based on taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in below KB article, a page(...) query and a componentPresentations(...) query can be used to fetch needed component presentations and then combine results on client.  It is possible to filter by page url only on the page(...) query and there is no filtering on the containerItems child element.  But it would be possible to filter on componentPresentations(...) by taxonomy and then combine both query results.
https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000010356